# Recent change to tag badges display on profile page harms accessibility

Tags: discussion, profile-page, tag-badges, accessibility

Recently the display of tag badges on profile page was changed from this

[image]

to this

[image]

As one can see the size of the badge circle is smaller now. From 13 pixels diameter it became 10 pixels (in the attached images, which I got using a Windows snipping tool, and web.archive.org).

That's a *1.7x reduction* in the colored circle *area*.

Not all of us have perfect vision. Making the circles smaller harms their visibility for such users. The levels of zoom that were comfortable before the change become no longer comfortable.

(for some reason the pictures here look enlarged compared to their real size by a factor of about 1.3x, so in reality they look smaller and the problem is more pronounced).

Can this change be reverted? Why change it in the first place? It looked fine before.

<sub>(no, these snapshots were not taken from my profile page, if anyone wonders; I was looking at someone else's page).</sub>